How to load custom language in python tree-sitter version 0.23.0
Python tree-sitter version 0.21.3 or earlier
from tree_sitter import Language, Parser

lang_path = "tree-sitter-test-lang/test-lang.so"

# Load the language
TESTLANG_LANGUAGE = Language(lang_path, 'testlang')

# Initialize the parser with the languages
parser = Parser()
parser.set_language(TESTLANG_LANGUAGE)

# Parse some code
source_code = b"""
let x = 10;
print x;
"""

tree = parser.parse(source_code)

# Explore the tree
root_node = tree.root_node

def print_node(node, indent=""):
    print(f"{indent}{node.type}: {node.text.decode('utf-8')}")
    for child in node.children:
        print_node(child, indent + "  ")

print_node(root_node)

Python tree-sitter version 0.23.0
In latest python version the definition of Language and Parser is changed. Language expects one argument of type tree-sitter.language and Parser is initialized directly with the output of Parser. Build_libary, set_language are removed and set_language
import tree_sitter_python as tspython
from tree_sitter import Language, Parser

PY_LANGUAGE = Language(tspython.language())

parser = Parser(PY_LANGUAGE)
tree = parser.parse(
    bytes(
        """
def foo():
    if bar:
        baz()
""",
        "utf8"
    )
)

The essence of my questions is how to use tree-sitter version 0.23.0 to load and parser with a custom-generated parser such as tree-sitter-test-lang/test-lang.so shared-object
lang_path = "tree-sitter-simple-lang/simple-lang.so"
# Load the language grammar

# Load the compiled language from the shared object file
my_language = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lang_path)
...

